# Where can I find the "targetHost" of my X509 certificate?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, x509certificate

While trying to set up an [`SslStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx), the example has a call in the client:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(targetHost);
```

For [`AuthenticateAsClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145060.aspx), the documentation states "`The value specified for targetHost must match the name on the server's certificate.`"

How can I find the `targetHost` of my x509 certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules vary slightly depending on the protocol. Cross-protocol harmonisation efforts have been made in [RFC 6125: *Representation and Verification of Domain-Based Application Service Identity within Internet Public Key Infrastructure Using X.509 (PKIX) Certificates in the Context of Transport Layer Security (TLS)*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125).

This being said, the RFC 6125 guidelines (meant to be applicable to any protocol that uses SSL/TLS) are more or less the same as those for HTTPS, which are defined in [RFC 2818 (*HTTP over TLS*), Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1).

In short, if the certificate has Subject Alternative Name (SAN) extensions of DNS type, one of them must be the target host name you're trying to connect to. When there are no such extensions, you must look into the Subject DN of the certificate and find the Common Name (CN) RDN: it must match the target host name.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in this field but I would suggest that `targetHost` is the name of the server and that your X509Certificate needs to be the certificate that was issued to authentify your server. In that case, it would be the [Subject property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.subject.aspx) of the certificate.